# How to properly shudown MongoDB before stopping its docker container?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, cypress

I would like to know how I can properly wait for and shutdown a MongoDB server before I stop and remove the docker image that contains it.

This teardown function stops and then removes a MongoDB docker image:

```
const teardown = async (failOnError = true) => {
  const dockerCommand = `docker stop ${imageName} && docker rm ${imageName}`

  return executeCommand(dockerCommand, environment, 'Finished database teardown', failOnError)
}
```

Execute command is a wrapper around Node's `child_process` [exec](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function that returns a promise, here is the full `executeCommand` helper:

```
const executeCommand = (command, envObject, resolveMsg, failOnError = true) => new
Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  exec(command, envObject, (err, stdout) => {
    if (err && failOnError) {
      console.error(`Command ${command} failed with error: `, err)
      reject(err)
    }

    // if we don't error we log the resolve message if one present
    if (!err && resolveMsg) console.log(resolveMsg)

    // resolve promise with err object if it exists, otherwise resolve with command output
    resolve(err || stdout)
  })
})
```

This is how the teardown function is called inside asynchronous functions called by Cypress before and after tests are run:

```
module.exports = async (on, config) => {
    on('before:run', async () => {
    console.log('BEFORE:RUN HOOK')

    // attempt to stop and remove docker images just in case teardown was not called at the end of
    // the last run. Note: will not fail or stop tests if teardown command fails
    await teardown(false)
    await setup()
    await checkHostAcceptingConnections()
  })

  on('after:run', async () => {
    console.log('AFTER:RUN HOOK')

    await teardown()
  })
}
```

Here's the thing: there is no guarantee that the teardown function inside the after run hook will be called (in case the test suite hangs). For this reason it is possible that the container is still up from the last run.

These methods do what they are told, but the problem is that if I call the teardown function and then immediately spin up the MongoDB docker container, the MongoDB outputs errors like "error: socket ended by other party" or "connection 0 to localhost closed".

Those errors completely disappear if I remove the teardown calls and just leave the docker image up and running - this is fine for local development but our CI may need to retry tests and I prefer to start the docker image with a completely clean slate.

I was under the impression that stopping, removing, and then starting the mongo docker image would also completely reset the image, thus clearing any state. That does not seem to be the case (new to docker).

How should I stop the MongoDB server? I only ever call `client.connect()` before doing some DB op, and then call `client.close()` after doing the operation, here is an example of how the database commands look:

```
const getDocsTotal = async () => {
  await client.connect()
  const collection = client.db('admin').collection('test-data')
  const totalDocs = await collection.countDocuments({})
  await client.close()
  return totalDocs
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using the MonogDB connect incorrectly (it creates a connection pool not a singleton connection) and didn't realise that `client.close()` does exactly what I need here.

I refactored the code to only call `client.connect()` once (during the before run hook), thus the working teardown command simply required one additional line of code:

```
// teardown the database by shutting down the MondoDB and using docker stop && docker remove
const teardown = async (failOnError = true) => {
  const dockerCommand = `docker stop ${imageName} && docker rm ${imageName}`

  await client.close()

  return executeCommand(dockerCommand, environment, 'Finished database teardown', failOnError)
}
```

This teardown command will wait for the client connection to close, this method also shuts down the database cleanly.